# How to Export-CSV with the correct identifying columns

Tags: powershell, ssl, ssl-certificate

This isnt providing me with the correct out-put. I'm wanting it to list in each column the correct information
                ID = $ID
                Website = $WebsiteURL
                Valid = $ValidTo
                Days_valid = $ValidDays

```
# Script: SSL_Epire_Check_Loop.ps1
# 
$WebsiteURLs= @("www.gcincentives.com", "www.google.com" )
$WebsitePort=443
$Threshold=120
$Severe=30
$ID=0
Write-Host "#   Website_URL:    Current Certificate:    Expiration Date:    Days Remaining: Errors:"
foreach ($WebsiteURL in $WebsiteURLs){
$CommonName=$WebsiteURL
$ID+=1
Try{
$Conn = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($WebsiteURL,$WebsitePort) 
Try {
$Stream = New-Object System.Net.Security.SslStream($Conn.GetStream(),$false, {
param($sender, $certificate, $chain, $sslPolicyErrors) 
return $true
})
$Stream.AuthenticateAsClient($CommonName) 

$Cert = $Stream.Get_RemoteCertificate()
$CN=(($cert.Subject -split "=")[1] -split ",")[0]
$ValidTo = [datetime]::Parse($Cert.GetExpirationDatestring())

$ValidDays = $($ValidTo - [datetime]::Now).Days
$MyFontColor="darkgreen"
if ($ValidDays -lt $Threshold) {
$MyFontColor="darkyellow"
} 
if ($ValidDays -lt $Severe) {
$MyFontColor="red"
}



#Write-Host "$ID    $WebsiteURL $CN $ValidTo    $ValidDays" -ForegroundColor $MyFontColor
}
Catch { Throw $_ }
Finally { $Conn.close() }
}
Catch {
Write-Host "$ID $WebsiteURL " $_.exception.innerexception.message -ForegroundColor red
}

}
$webcert = @{ 
            ID = $ID
            Website = $WebsiteURL
            Valid = $ValidTo
            Days_valid = $ValidDays
            }

$webcert | export-csv -Path c:\users\rwhite\test1.csv
```

Comment: So... what's currently happening?

Comment: #TYPE System.Collections.Hashtable      
IsReadOnly IsFixedSize IsSynchronized Keys Values SyncRoot Count
FALSE FALSE FALSE System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection System.Object 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Export-Csv` expects a list of (custom) objects, not a hashtable.

```
New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $webcert |
    Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: That fixed one part but it only put the second URL into the csv and not the first one.

Comment: I needed to change where the export was at. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Create the object *inside* your loop.